# jQuery multiple parent() calls

Tags: jquery, parent-child, parent

I have this jQuery:

`$(this).parent().parent().find(".license_tooltip").stop(true, true).fadeIn(200);`

The `$(this)` object is nested within two `div`s like this:

```
<div>
    <div>
        <a href="">$(this) object</a>
    </div>

    <div>
        <a href="">object to fade in</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Can someone point me in the right direction to making my jQuery more streamlined? The structure presented above is replicated multiple times, so using classes and IDs is impossible.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use a class (or any other selectable attribute) and [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to claim to the parent you want, like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div>
        <a href="">$(this) object</a>
    </div>

    <div>
        <a href="">object to fade in</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

And for the script:

```
$(this).closest(".container").find(".license_tooltip").stop(true, true).fadeIn(200);
```

Comment: Thank you :-) I'll add classes to my containing `div`s

Comment: Thank you as well, even though I'm late to the party! I tried to do parent of parent etc. etc. in a table structure, forgetting to SIMPLY (as you did) look for the closest parent in the structure that has a certain class. Makes it a lot easier and cleaner!

Answer (score 4):

You could use the `.parents( [ selector ] )` [here is a link](http://api.jquery.com/parents/)

It will traverse more than one parent up.

Answer (score 3):

use `parents()`

```
$(this)
    .parents('selector for the parent you need to look in')
    .find(".license_tooltip")
    .stop(true, true)
    .fadeIn(200);
```